# Bash quoted array expansion

Tags: arrays, bash, quotes

WHen I write a bash program I typically construct calls like follows:

```
declare -a mycmd=( command.ext "arg1 with space" arg2 thing etc )

"${mycmd[@]}" || echo "Failed: foo"
```

Where `die foo` is a bash function that prints `Error foo` and exits.

But if I want to be clear about the error reason, I want to print the failed command:

```
"${mycmd[@]}" || echo "Failed: foo: ${mycmd[*]}"
```

So the user can run the dead command and find out *why*.  However, quoting is lost on this pass - the Failed message arguments that have spaces or escaped characters are not printed in a way that can be cut-n-pasted and run.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a compact way to fix this problem?

---

I think the problem is the way bash deals with argument parsing for commands, and the way (builtin) echo handles arguments.  Another way of stating the problem is:

How can I *print* the quotes around arguments with spaces in the following bash example (which must be run as a script, not in immediate mode):

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir qatest; cd qatest
declare -a myargs=(1 2 "3 4")
touch "${myargs[@]}"
ls
echo "${myargs[@]}"
```

actual result:

```
1  2  3 4
1 2 3 4
```

desired result

```
1  2  3 4
1 2 "3 4"
```

OR

```
1  2  3 4
"1" "2" "3 4"
```

In few additional bash code characters.

Comment: You should prefer [`printf '%q'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12985540/113632) or Bash 4.4's `"${mycmd[@]@Q}"` expansion over `printf "'%s'"`. Naive quoting like this will fail in a number of cases, e.g. `myargs=(1 2 "3' 4")`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your problem is with `echo`. It is getting the correct number of parameters, with some parameters containing spaces, but it's output loses the distinction of spaces between parameters and spaces within parameters.

Instead, you can use `printf(1)` to output the parameters and always include quotes, making use of printf's feature that applies the format string successively to parameters when there are more parameters than format specifiers in the format string:

```
echo "Failed: foo:" $(printf "'%s' " "${mycmd[@]}")
```

That will put single quotes around each argument, even if it is not needed:

```
Failed: foo: 'command.ext' 'arg1 with space' 'arg2' 'thing' 'etc'
```

I've used single quotes to ensure that other shell metacharacters are not mishandled. This will work for all characters except single quote itself - i.e. if you have a parameter containing a single quote, the output from the above command will not cut and paste correctly. This is likely the closest you will get without getting messy.

Edit: Almost 5 years later and since I answered this question, bash 4.4 has been released. This has the `"${var@Q}"` expansion which quotes the variable such that it can be parsed back by bash.

This simplifies this answer to:

```
echo "Failed: foo: " "${mycmd[@]@Q}"
```

This will correctly handle single quotes in an argument, which my earlier version did not.

Comment: For all that look for a documentation of that bash 4.4 feature: https://lwn.net/Articles/701009/
With a discussion of probably use cases below that I found to be insightful.

I'd like to thank @camh you for being thorough enough to follow up on this with the bash 4.4 feature. You probably saved me a ton of rewrite later, had I not discovered this at this point! Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

bash's printf command has a %q format that adds appropriate quotes to the strings as they're printed:

```
echo "Failed: foo:$(printf " %q" "${mycmd[@]}")"
```

Mind you, its idea of the "best" way to quote something isn't always the same as mine, e.g. it tends to prefer escaping funny characters instead of wrapping the string in quotes.  For example:

```
crlf=$'\r\n'
declare -a mycmd=( command.ext "arg1 with space 'n apostrophe" "arg2 with control${crlf} characters" )
echo "Failed: foo:$(printf " %q" "${mycmd[@]}")"
```

Prints:

```
Failed: foo: command.ext arg1\ with\ space\ \'n\ apostrophe $'arg2 with control\r\n characters'
```

Comment: "Escaping funny characters" is simpler implementation logic than quoting.

Answer (score 3):

How about `declare -p quotedarray`?

-- edit --

Acctually, `declare -p quotedarray` will satisfy you purpose well. If you insist on the output format of the result, then I have a small trick would do the work, but just for the indexed array not associative one.

```
declare -a quotedarray=(1 2 "3 4")
temparray=( "${quotedarray[@]/#/\"}" ) #the outside double quotes are critical
echo ${temparray[@]/%/\"}
```

Comment: yields:
`declare -a quotedarray='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")'`.  Doesn't seem to help, for me.

Comment: @AlexBrown Are you sure about you result? Please try it again. It is impossible to get your result if you defined the array this way `declare -a quotedarray=(1 2 "3 4")`

Comment: although you raise an interesting point, my example seems to be wrong somehow.

Comment: @AlexBrown If you get the result `declare -a quotedarray='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")'`, then the quotedarray must be defined to `(1 2 3 4)` with four elements. Please double check the array, or unset it and retry.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem, it turns out I need a bash _script_ to show the problem so I have amended the example.

Answer (score 1):

A cumbersome method (which only quotes arguments that contain spaces):

```
declare -a myargs=(1 2 "3 4")
for arg in "${myargs[@]}"; do
    # testing if the argument contains space(s)
    if [[ $arg =~ \  ]]; then
      # enclose in double quotes if it does 
      arg=\"$arg\"
    fi 
    echo -n "$arg "
done
```

Output:

```
1 2 "3 4"
```

---

By the way, with regards to `quoting is lost on this pass`, note that the quotes are *never* saved. `" "` is a special character that tells the shell to treat whatever is inside as a single field/argument (i.e. not split it). On the other hand, literal quotes (typed like this `\"`) are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

### Another approach

```
# echo_array.sh

contains_space(){ [[ "$1" =~ " " ]]; return $?; }
maybe_quote_one(){ contains_space "$1"  &&  echo \'"$1"\'  ||  echo "$1"; }
maybe_quote(){ while test "$1"; do maybe_quote_one "$1"; shift; done; }

arridx(){ echo '${'$1'['$2']}'; }
arrindir(){ echo $(eval echo `arridx $1 $2`); }
arrsize(){ echo `eval echo '${'#$1'[@]}'`; }

echo_array()
{ 
    echo -n "$1=( "
    local i=0
    for (( i=0; i < `arrsize a`; i++ )); do
        echo -n $(maybe_quote "$(arrindir $1 $i)") ''
    done
    echo ")"
}
```

#### Usage:

```
source echo_array.sh
a=( foo bar baz "It was hard" curious '67 - 00' 44 'my index is 7th' )
echo_array a
# a=( foo bar baz 'It was hard' curious '67 - 00' 44 'my index is 7th'  )
arrindir a 7
# my index is 7th
arrindir a 0
# foo
arrsize a
# 8
```

**$ bash --version**

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to put the code in a function so it is easier to reuse and document:

```
function myjoin
{
   local list=("${@}")
   echo $(printf "'%s', " "${list[@]}")
}

declare -a colorlist=()
colorlist+=('blue')
colorlist+=('red')
colorlist+=('orange')

echo "[$(myjoin ${colorlist[@]})]"
```

Note how I added the comma in the solution because I am generating code with a bash script.

[EDIT: fix problem that EM0 pointed out that it is returning ['blue',]]

Comment: This returns `['blue',]` for me.