# jq - how to get all the values from a object within object

Tags: bash, jq

I have the following json object.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
    "kind": "Deployment",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1",
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-02-22T17:35:22Z",
        "generation": 1,
        "labels": {
            "app": "addresses",
            "group": "de.test",
            "provider": "jkube",
            "version": "2.3.0-3191"
        },
        "name": "addresses",
        "namespace": "linkerd",
        "resourceVersion": "910972",
        "uid": "aaee0eb0-5d66-44dd-b9b0-35e17bec4cf4"
    },
    "spec": {
        "progressDeadlineSeconds": 600,
        "replicas": 1,
        "revisionHistoryLimit": 2,
        "selector": {
            "matchLabels": {
                "app": "addresses",
                "group": "de.test",
                "provider": "jkube"
            }
        },
        "strategy": {
            "rollingUpdate": {
                "maxSurge": 1,
                "maxUnavailable": "50%"
            },
            "type": "RollingUpdate"
        },
        "template": {
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "jkube.io/git-branch": "develop",
                    "jkube.io/git-commit": "77aaca38564dffff0ce10a8c70d4139b33f677b2",
                    "jkube.io/git-url": "http://bitbucket.org/testzentrale/test-monorepo",
                    "jkube.io/scm-tag": "HEAD",
                    "jkube.io/scm-url": "https://bitbucket.org/testzentrale/test-monorepo/test/addresses"
                },
                "creationTimestamp": null,
                "labels": {
                    "app": "addresses",
                    "group": "de.test",
                    "provider": "jkube",
                    "version": "2.3.0-3191"
                },
                "namespace": "test-testing"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "env": [
                            {
                                "name": "SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT",
                                "valueFrom": {
                                    "fieldRef": {
                                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                                        "fieldPath": "metadata.namespace"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "SENTRY_SERVERNAME",
                                "valueFrom": {
                                    "fieldRef": {
                                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                                        "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "SENTRY_TAGS",
                                "value": "service:addresses"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "SENTRY_RELEASE",
                                "value": "2.3.0-3191"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "JAVA_OPTIONS",
                                "value": "-Xms64m -Xmx384m"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE",
                                "valueFrom": {
                                    "fieldRef": {
                                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                                        "fieldPath": "metadata.namespace"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "HOSTNAME",
                                "valueFrom": {
                                    "fieldRef": {
                                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                                        "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "envFrom": [
                            {
                                "configMapRef": {
                                    "name": "db-mssql-asd-connection"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "secretRef": {
                                    "name": "db-mssql-asd-connection"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "configMapRef": {
                                    "name": "db-postgre-asd-connection"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "secretRef": {
                                    "name": "db-postgre-asd-connection"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "configMapRef": {
                                    "name": "app-url"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "secretRef": {
                                    "name": "app-token"
                                }
                            }                                                      
                        ],
                        "image": "myrepo/test/addresses:testing-2.3.0-3191",
                        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                        "livenessProbe": {
                            "failureThreshold": 3,
                            "httpGet": {
                                "path": "/",
                                "port": 8080,
                                "scheme": "HTTP"
                            },
                            "initialDelaySeconds": 300,
                            "periodSeconds": 10,
                            "successThreshold": 1,
                            "timeoutSeconds": 1
                        },
                        "name": "spring-boot",
                        "ports": [
                            {
                                "containerPort": 8080,
                                "name": "http",
                                "protocol": "TCP"
                            },
                            {
                                "containerPort": 9779,
                                "name": "prometheus",
                                "protocol": "TCP"
                            },
                            {
                                "containerPort": 8778,
                                "name": "jolokia",
                                "protocol": "TCP"
                            }
                        ],
                        "readinessProbe": {
                            "failureThreshold": 2,
                            "httpGet": {
                                "path": "/actuator/health",
                                "port": 8080,
                                "scheme": "HTTP"
                            },
                            "initialDelaySeconds": 20,
                            "periodSeconds": 10,
                            "successThreshold": 1,
                            "timeoutSeconds": 1
                        },
                        "resources": {
                            "limits": {
                                "memory": "1000Mi"
                            },
                            "requests": {
                                "cpu": "100m",
                                "memory": "500Mi"
                            }
                        },
                        "securityContext": {
                            "privileged": false
                        },
                        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                        "volumeMounts": [
                            {
                                "mountPath": "/deployments/config",
                                "name": "config"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                "restartPolicy": "Always",
                "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
                "securityContext": {},
                "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "configMap": {
                            "defaultMode": 420,
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "key": "application.properties",
                                    "path": "application.properties"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "addresses"
                        },
                        "name": "config"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "status": {
        "conditions": [
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2023-02-22T17:35:23Z",
                "lastUpdateTime": "2023-02-22T17:35:23Z",
                "message": "Deployment does not have minimum availability.",
                "reason": "MinimumReplicasUnavailable",
                "status": "False",
                "type": "Available"
            },
            {
                "lastTransitionTime": "2023-02-22T17:45:24Z",
                "lastUpdateTime": "2023-02-22T17:45:24Z",
                "message": "ReplicaSet \"addresses-dd575cdc9\" has timed out progressing.",
                "reason": "ProgressDeadlineExceeded",
                "status": "False",
                "type": "Progressing"
            }
        ],
        "observedGeneration": 1,
        "replicas": 1,
        "unavailableReplicas": 1,
        "updatedReplicas": 1
    }
}
```

I need to extract all the `name` properties of the `configMapRef`

So I used the`jq` to extract like below:

```
cat file.json | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[] | select(.configMapRef) '
```

And I get the below output:

```
{
  "configMapRef": {
    "name": "db-mssql-asd-connection"
  }
}
{
  "configMapRef": {
    "name": "db-postgre-asd-connection"
  }
}
{
  "configMapRef": {
    "name": "app-url"
  }
}
```

But I need to get the `name` so my output looks like this:

```
db-mssql-asd-connection
db-postgre-asd-connection
app-url
```

I tried many things such as;

```
// not wokring
jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[] | select(.configMapRef) | jq .name'

// not wokring
jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[] | select(.configMapRef.name) | jq .name'
```

And I want to store thee values as a `bash` array so I can iterate through them. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Comment: remove on line 6 `,` at the end

Comment: Is this sample JSON is as-is or you wrote a typo by error?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538320/xidel-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-specific-nested-values-from-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the `envFrom` objects that `has` the property, then get the desired property in the final result.

```
$ jq -r '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[]
  | select(has("configMapRef")).configMapRef.name' file.json
db-mssql-asd-connection
db-postgre-asd-connection
app-url
```

Comment: `parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 7, column 9`

Comment: Yes... the example json is technically not valid json (excess trailing comma)... but the  intent is obviously clear with a trivially fixable error.

Comment: You should mention that

Comment: If there was an actual structural error in the json and it was unclear what it would be intended, then the question would be unanswerable and we would have to wait for clarification. But again, the structure was obvious and any parser that wasn't as strict as jq wouldn't complain. There's no need for any of us to either since it doesn't change how we would approach the question or answers.

Answer (score 1):

###### The jq part

The way you are using `select` isn't productive. `select` emits either nothing (in which case that particular pipe branch dies), or its whole input (in which case you'd still need to descend into `.configMapRef` yourself). My suggestion is to unconditionally descend into it (and into `.name` as well), which may produce `null` values in the otherwise dying branches. You can filter them out either explicitly by using the alternative operator `//` with `empty`, or directly selecting either all non-null `| values` or, more constrainingly, only `| strings`. Either way, use the `-r` option to output raw text (instead of JSON):

```
jq -r '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[].configMapRef.name // empty' file.json
```

```
jq -r '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[].configMapRef.name | values' file.json
```

```
jq -r '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[].configMapRef.name | strings' file.json
```

```
db-mssql-asd-connection
db-postgre-asd-connection
app-url
```

###### The bash loop part

There are ways to escape the output (search for `@sh`) and to format it e.g. to fit to a `declare` statement ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75088434/2158479)), which will generate an indexed bash array. But in this case, it'd be simpler to just iterate over the lines output:

```bash
while read -r line
do … "$line" …
done < <(jq -r '…' file.json)
```

Comment: `parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 7, column 9`

Comment: @GillesQuénot This is (obviously) a copy-paste error, not present in the original data, as OP themselves has no issues executing other jq filters. See "So I used the jq to extract like below […] And I get the below output".

Answer (score 0):

##### With some Unix* pipes. Works also with your broken JSON, unlike the other answers

`grep` and `regex` are *universal*. `gron` makes the things sufficiently *atomic* to be able to use `grep` *the reliable way*.

For simple task, `jq` is the way to go, but if you need > 10 mn to find the good syntax, `gron` is a very nice tool to have in the *toolchest*.

The reason to use this, is that I refuse to go too deeper with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq). If you need to know another 'language' for each type of structured data files, it's a mess. I prefer simpler/shorter solutions. Here one:

```
$ yq . file.json | gron | grep -oP 'configMapRef\.name = "\K[^"]+' 
db-mssql-asd-connection
db-postgre-asd-connection
app-url
```

I use `yq`, because it's less strict than `gron` and `jq`:

```
$ jq . file.json
parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 7, column 9
```

and

```
$ gron file.json
failed to form statements: invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
```

If the `json` was better formatted, I was able to wrote:

```
gron 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/7da057b951c182785dfb837194388350/raw/eaf064c6b44c8304e111fa4e6ee3638d47a4ef48/object.json' |
    grep -oP 'configMapRef\.name = "\K[^"]+'
```

- Python [`yg`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) works also with...
- golang [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)
- [`gron`](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron) *Make JSON greppable!*

Comment: Why use grep when jq (and yq) can do it? Processing json as raw text seems rather pointless when there are json processing tools available.

Comment: If you read carefully, `jq` give error here. And I explained my point of view with complicated 'language' like `jq`. For simple task, it's the way to go, but if you need > 10 mn to find the good syntax, `gron` is a very nice tool. And `grep` and `regex` are _universal_. `gron` makes the things sufficiently _atomic_ to be able to use `grep` the reliable way

Answer (score -1):

```
$ jq -r '.spec.template.spec.containers[].envFrom[].configMapRef|select( . != null )|.name' file.json
db-mssql-asd-connection
db-postgre-asd-connection
app-url

Using AWK
$ awk -F'"' '/configMapRef/{getline; print $--NF}' <(json_pp <file.json) 
$ awk -F'"' '/configMapRef/{getline; print $--NF}' <(jq -r . file.json)
db-mssql-asd-connection
db-postgre-asd-connection
app-url
```

Comment: `parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 7, column 9`

Comment: And for `json_pp`: `unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 163 (before ",\n        "creation...") at /home/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/json_pp line 59.`

Comment: The original file has an error on line 6 `,` at the end

Comment: @GillesQuénot it works.. Have no erros

Comment: @ufopilot You could [shorten](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L63) `select( . != null )` to `values` (since jq 1.6)

Comment: You removed the trailing `,` then

Comment: @GillesQuénot yes i did